# NSUserDefaults: how to get only the keys I've set

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

All of the methods to get keys from NSUserDefaults return heaps of keys from domains other than the app itself (e.g., NSGlobalDomain).  I just want the keys and values that my app has set.  This is useful for debugging and verifying that there are no orphaned keys, etc.

I could ignore the keys that aren't mine (if I know all of them -- during development I may have set keys I'm no longer using), but there might be a collision of keys in other domains and I'll not see my app's value.

Other discussions suggest looking at the dictionary **file** associated with the app, but that's not very elegant.

How can I get only my app's keys form NSUserdefaults?

Comment: It is not clear what you need it for (terminal, app...). If you app is going to be sandboxed you will not be able to see other defaults. BTW correct approach is to registerDefaults for the keys you need (which happens once and doesn't rewrite the key) and later just ask for their value.

Comment: I want to do this in my app during development, and I'm only interested in the keys and values that I've set.  Over time I've changed or stopped using some of the keys and that's why I want to see all the keys I've used.  I use the userDefaults for app settings, and it's useful for me to see the settings in the log each time I launch the app during testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant approach

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSDictionary *dict = [defaults persistentDomainForName:bundleIdentifier];
```

File approach:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Library/Preferences/%@.plist",bundleIdentifier];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
```

Tested with sandboxing.

Comment: Excellent, accepted.  I've added two lines to remove some system stuff in the plist (at least it's in mine): `NSMutableDictionary *myUserDefaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict]; [myUserDefaults removeObjectsForKeys:@[ @"CaptionDWA_CaptionBehavior", @"NSWindow Frame NSFontPanel" ]];`

Answer (score 0):

[Marek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796001/2209609) code updated to Swift 5:

```
guard let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else { return }
let dict = UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: bundleIdentifier)
```